# Flutter not installed on UBUNTU 20.04 LTS

Tags: flutter, android-studio-3.0, ubuntu-20.04

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.I installed flutter SDK using `sudo snap install flutter --classic` and then i installed android studio using `sudo snap install andriod-studio --classic` but when i run
`flutter doctor` in terminal it outputs this:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
      more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories
```

N when i open any flutter project in VS code and hit `flutter run` in terminal connecting physical device for debugging, it says:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on DUB LX1 in debug mode...
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/home/suraj/Projects/wordpair/android/settings.gradle' (/home/suraj/.gradle/caches/6.7/scripts/f0emg6u6oecmxqzgk5g9nn4ui).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 7s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         9.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I just want to run flutter project on my android mobile for debugging. so could someone please tell me the problem here? Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: did you open android studio and try to run it,also `flutter doctor --android-licenses`,also make sure you have installed android studio@Suraj Oberai

Comment: i did install android studio using snap but still it's saying not installed while running ```flutter doctor```

Comment: can you open android studio?@Suraj Oberai

Answer (score 1):

Read the errors when they appear. It's saying two things, with steps how to solve them:

1: run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

2: install android studio.

3: Install android studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux) on linux, not by using snap.

Comment: i run ```flutter doctor --android-licenses``` and got this: ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema```

Comment: @SurajOberai I edited my answer. Install android studio from that link, not from snap, and configure flutter dr to find your path for android studio afterwards.

Comment: i had also installed android studio by extracting zip files long time ago, now i have two icons of android studio one from installing android studio via extraction of zip and another from snap. I successfully removed the snap one but still i am getting android studio not installed while running ```flutter doctor```

Comment: to correct this issue, you need to tell flutter doctor where android studio is installed. And point it to your zip installation directory, please try that and update what happens.

Comment: could u tell me how can i remove the android studio installed from extraction of zip, please ? i will try to uninstall and then re-install. I tried deleting all the directories like android, android studios and every directory related to android studio but no luck. the icon is still there.

Comment: @SurajOberai I believe this question is for a different topic, but read about purging an installation on linux. Before purging anything though, can you run the .zip installed android studio?

Comment: many of these causes are occurred due to installing the software from snap-craft or apt  s/w package managers.Try to use original Software link from appropriate website to download and extract in proper local folder.

Answer (score 0):

many of these causes are occurred due to installing the software from snap-craft or apt s/w package managers.Try to use original Software link from appropriate website to download and extract in proper local folder.

Because those s/w package managers doesn't updating the software to latest version or latest bug fixes.